# How to Pass props in React component?

Tags: reactjs

I am using reactjs. I have a componnt that is written like this:

```
import MyComponent from './Component';


 const test = [
    {
      id: '1',
      Component: FirstComponent,
    },
    {
      id: '2',
      Component: MyComponent,
    },
  ];

  return (
    <Demo
      components={test} 
    />
  );
```

In this case How can I pass props for `MyComponent`?

Comment: can you show full your source code. your example look so confuse @@

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to pass additional props on to `MyComponent` then you should define an anonymous component in the config so you can pass new props to the child component. Don't forget to also pass `props` on through to the child component.

```
const test = [
  {
    id: '1',
    Component: FirstComponent,
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    Component: (props) => (
      <MyComponent {...props} prop1={prop1} prop2={prop2} etc />
    ),
  },
];
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly i want to introduce what is props . props means property that you are passing though your jsx code to functions or we can say pure functions . let me give you a demo with small element like H1 Tag .

I am creating a **h1.js** File .

```
import React from 'react';

// arrow function that get props
const H1 = (props) => {
     return '<h1>{props.text}</h1>';
}
export default H1;
```

Now when you want to use this function just import and pass though props like

#Main.js

```
import React from 'react';
import H1 from './h1.js';
class Main extends React.Component{
   constructor() {
     super();
   }
   render(){
     return(
        <>
          <H1 text="pass what you want"></H1>
        </>
     );
   }
}
```

so may be you will get idea how it work right ;)